# Differentiable function by definition

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

$$z=x|y|, \ P=(1,0)$$
I would like to know if this multi-variable function is differentiable at (1,0).
I calculated both partial derivatives by definition, and one of them doesn't exist at (1,0) so the function isn't differentiable at that point. Is this correct?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, if the function is differential then all partial derivatives must exist. If you have seen that some partial derivatives don't exist then you are correct in concluding that the function is not differentiable.